# PHP Mistake - Whats wrong here?

Tags: redirect, author

could anybody tell me please whats wrong with this code ? I get an PHP mistake and cant finde the reason why.

What I want to do is, in the author.php if the author.php is shown as the author php of an person that is subscriber, I want to redirect. If an author.php is shown of any other roles, show it.

```
$curauth = (get_query_var('author_name')) ? get_user_by('slug', get_query_var('author_name')) : get_userdata(get_query_var('author'));

if ( get_user_role($curauth->ID) === 'subscriber' ):
    wp_redirect( 'http://redirect-here.com');
    endif;
```

Comment: what is the exact wording of the error message or warning?

Comment: Nothing...white side

Comment: @RodneyHawk [enable debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and the error messages will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: print_r() and die() should be your friend here. You're assuming $curauth is a valid object with ID set. Maybe you should check if those exist. Also, not sure get_user_role is a function. Try $current_user = get_userdata( $user_id );$current_user_roles = $current_user->roles; then check against the values in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official *code reference*:

> wp_redirect() does not exit automatically, and should almost always be
>   followed by a call to exit;

So, you need to call **exit** after the redirect:

```
$curauth = (get_query_var('author_name')) ? get_user_by('slug', get_query_var('author_name')) : get_userdata(get_query_var('author'));

if ( get_user_role($curauth->ID) === 'subscriber' ):
    wp_redirect( 'http://redirect-here.com' );
    exit;  //here!
endif;
```

Comment: Ok thanks...but the php mistake still keeps going on